# Using IF statement to create a schedule with dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a schedule with dates using IF and EDATE formulas.
So, I have a Start date and End Date and I want to create a schedule with 3 month periods between those dates.

For example: the start date is 01.01.2017 and end date is 01.01.2018.
my schedule would look like:

- 01.01.17
- 01.04.17
- 01.07.17
- 01.10.17
- 01.01.18

I can create a schedule successfully if the last period is 3 month or shorter, however I'm having a difficulty to create schedule where the last period is longer than 3 month.
For example, the start date is 01.01.2017 and end date is 01.02.2018 and I would like to make the last period 4 month.

I would appreciate if you share some ideas or suggestions.

Comment: How do you create the schedule if the last period is 3 months or shorter and where do you get the periods from?

Answer (score 0):

Place the start date in **A1** and then end date in **A2**.  In **B1** enterr:

```
=A1
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)+3,DAY(B1))>$A$2,"",DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)+3,DAY(B1))))
```

and copy down.  Column **B** are the schedule dates *without adjustment*.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)+3,DAY(B1))>$A$2,$A$2,B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

As you see, the last period has been expanded from 3 months to four months.